# Undefined vertexUv on merging BufferGeometries loaded from an .obj file?

Tags: three.js

I am loading an `.obj` file using `THREE.OBJLoader` with three.js `r86`.

I would like to merge the children of this object into a single mesh.

Since the loaded geometries of the meshes are `BufferGeometry` objects, first I transform them into `Geometry` objects then I perform the merge.

From my understanding there is no way to perform the merge easily directly on the `BufferGeometry` objects as of yet.

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'Temple-model.obj', function ( object ) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();        

    for (var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++) {
        var c = object.children[i];
        if (c instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            var g = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( c.geometry );
            geometry.merge(g);
        }
    }
    var merged = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(merged);
});
```

This seems to work but provokes raises this warning on the line on calling the `render` function of the `renderer`.

```
THREE.DirectGeometry.fromGeometry(): Undefined vertexUv  18483
```

Why does this happen and what are some better alternatives to achieve this?